# Comparing NSNumbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumber

A user inputs a number (either a float or integer), and it must be greater than a lower bound.

This is the code to get the number from the UITextField:

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *currentNumber = [f numberFromString:self.textfield.text];
[f release];
```

The lower bound is often 0.1 (`lowerBound` is an NSNumber)

If I have this code and I enter 0.1 into the textfield, then `isValid` remains `YES`.

```
BOOL isValid = YES;
if ([currentNumber floatValue] < [self.lowerBound floatValue]) {
    isValid = NO;
}
```

However I though it would be better to do:

```
BOOL isValid = YES;
if ([currentNumber compare:self.lowerBound] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    isValid = NO;
}
```

However I enter 0.1 again (and the lowerBound is still 0.1) the if statement evaluates to true (as if currentNumber is less than self.lowerBound).

The code works as expected for 0.11 and above. I also have a higher bound:

```
BOOL isValid = YES;
if ([currentNumber compare:self.higherBound] == NSOrderDescending) {
    isValid = NO;
}
```

And this works as expected, including when I enter the same value as the higherBound (10 in most cases)

As I understand it the `compare:` method on NSNumber compares the values and not the addresses of the objects, so why doesn't it work on the lower bound?

Answer (score 2):

Because floating point numbers are not exact - the 0.1 in the one NSNumber may be different from the one in the other NSNumber.

Comment: So then why does getting the float value "out of" the NSNumber then work?

Comment: @Jonathan. we don't know - everything is implementation defined. From Apple's docs, NSNumber isn't even required to store numbers using the type of which it was created (a float may be stored as a double, a BOOL as an int, whichever is better for performance).

Comment: So the recommended way to compare 2 NSNumbers is not to use the compare: method but to convert it to a primitive type first?

Comment: @Jonathan. that's not true as-is. The main problem is not with your code, neither with Apple's - it's the fact that floats aren't exact. It may have been the case that the exact opposite occurs (i. e. comparing scalars doesn't work, only `compare:`).